# Understanding numpy array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an input array X.

```
[[68 72  2  0 15 74 34 20 36 3]
[20  2 79 20 80 45 15 20 11 45]
[42 13 80 35  3  3 38 70 74 75]
[80 20 78  5 34 13 80 11 20 72]
[20 13 15 20 13 75 81 20 75 13]
[20 32 15 20 29  2 75  3 45 80]
[72 74 80 20 64 45 79 74 20  1]
[37 20  6  5 15 20 80 45 29 20]
[15 20 13 75 80 65 15 35 20 60]
[20 75  2 13 78 20 15 45 20 72]]
```

Can someone help me understand the below code -

```
y = np.zeros_like(x)
y[:, :-1], y[:, -1] = x[:, 1:], x[:, 0]
```

Comment: Have you tried the code to see what it does?

Answer (score 3):

First:

```
y = np.zeros_like(x)
```

This creates an array full of zeros with the same size as `x` and stores it in `y`.

Then `y[:, :-1], y[:, -1]` <- all but the last column, and the last column

is set `=` to:

`x[:, 1:], x[:, 0]` <- all but the first column, and the first column.

It's a very inefficient way to roll the first column to the last.

A much better way to do this is

```
y = np.roll(x, -1, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand for:

```
y = np.zeros_like(x)
y[:, :-1] = x[:, 1:]
y[:, -1] = x[:, 0]
```

Which translates to:

Make `y` an array of `0`s of the same dimensions as `x`.

Set the part of `y` which includes all the rows and all columns except the last one equal to the part of `x` which includes all the rows and all columns except the first one.

Set the last column of `y` equal to the first column of `x`.

Basically, `y` will look like `x` except with the first column removed and tacked on at the end.